# Windows - how to map remote drive over another remote drive

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a computer A, that is in network with computer B. Computer B is in network with computer C. (computer B has two interfaces).

Is there any way to access filesystem of computer C from computer A?
I tried symbolic/junction links on bridge computer (B), but that does not work.

I need a drive mapped like this on computer A: \\compB\\compC\compBsharedfolder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is file sharing enabled on the computer with the files you want to share?